# Delete gesture from gesturefile

Tags: android

i am developing a small gesture app that creates and saves the gesture into the file and is based on the gestureBuilder code from the android samples.

i want to delete all gestures stored in the file and the porting of code goes like this

```
private static GestureLibrary sStore;
final GestureLibrary store = sStore;
 if (store.load()) 
                    {
                        for (String name : store.getGestureEntries()) 
                        {
                           for (Gesture gesture : store.getGestures(name)) 
                           {
                                final NamedGesture namedGesture = new NamedGesture();
                                namedGesture.gesture = gesture;
                                namedGesture.name = name;

                                sStore.removeGesture(namedGesture.name, namedGesture.gesture);
                                sStore.save();
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

however on running this gives gives exception like this

03-13 14:42:07.009: E/AndroidRuntime(905): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 14:42:07.009: E/AndroidRuntime(905): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
03-13 14:42:07.009: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:796)
03-13 14:42:07.009: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:823)
03-13 14:42:07.009: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at com.likith.gesturebuilder.GestureBuilderActivity$2$1.onClick(GestureBuilderActivity.java:127)
03-13 14:42:07.009: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
03-13 14:42:07.009: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 14:42:07.009: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-13 14:42:07.009: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-13 14:42:07.009: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 14:42:07.009: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-13 14:42:07.009: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-13 14:42:07.009: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-13 14:42:07.009: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Is there any method to delete all gestures from the gesture file
pls help ...

Comment: I am guessing you could try sStore.clear() to remove all entries

Comment: No that does'nt work ...

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want to delete all the gesture (entries) of the gesturestore file:

```
if (store.load()) {
                try {
                    List list = new ArrayList();
                    for (String name : store.getGestureEntries()) {
                        list.add(name);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        store.removeEntry(list.get(i).toString());
                        store.save();
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
```

2) If you want to delete only one entry at time:

```
if (store.load()) {
                try {
                    for (String name : store.getGestureEntries()) {
                        if (name.equals("name of the entry you want to delete")) {
                            Gesture gesture = store.getGestures(name).get(0);
                            store.removeGesture(name, gesture);
                            store.save();
                        }
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
```

I hope it works for you.